# Angular - error TS2307: Cannot find module './_helpers/must-match.validator'

Tags: angular

In my Angular--11 project, I created a helper as shown below:

must-match.validator.ts

```js
import {
  FormGroup
} from '@angular/forms';

// custom validator to check that two fields match
// tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
export function MustMatch(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
    const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
    const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];

    if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors.mustMatch) {
      // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl
      return;
    }

    // set error on matchingControl if validation fails
    if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
      matchingControl.setErrors({
        mustMatch: true
      });
    } else {
      matchingControl.setErrors(null);
    }
  }
}
```

In the auth.module which hosts the user registration component and the helper, I did:

```
import { MustMatch } from './_helpers/must-match.validator';
```

When I did this in the user-registration where I'm to use it:

```
import { MustMatch } from './_helpers/must-match.validator';
```

I got this error:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module './_helpers/must-match.validator' or its corresponding type declarations.

> 10 import { MustMatch } from './_helpers/must-match.validator';

Folder structure:

[![Folder structure][1]][1]

The component using the helper is directly inside pages:

pages/signin

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: You are using a relative path, so it could be related to the folder structure. Is the user-registration component in a sub-folder? You might need to use `import { MustMatch } from '../_helpers/must-match.validator';`

Comment: @JSONDerulo - Still saying cannot find module

Comment: Can you share your folder structure then?

Comment: @JSONDerulo - I have updated my code with the folder structure:     The component using the helper is directly inside pages:

Comment: So the page that uses the helpers is inside a sub-folder of the `pages` folder? then you need to provide the correct path: `import { MustMatch } from '../../_helpers/must-match.validator';`